# Importing AdMob into my unity project don't show the asset menu

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I'm following the official [AdMob tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start) to use it into my Unity project.

So far what I've done is:

- Downloaded the plugin
- Go to import package and then select the just downloaded plugin `GoogleMobileAds-v3.18.0`. Select `GoogleMobileAds` and `Plugins`. I **can't** select `PlayServicesResolver`, it's already installed I guess.
- Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve
- This results in a message box telling me `Resolution succeded`
- Then I repeat the same but with `Force Resolve`.

Here it comes the problem. The `Google Mobile Ads` menu doesn't appear on my Unity.

[image]

So I can't continue with the configuration of AdMob. I've tried several things like:

- Closing Unity and opening it back again, with the result of loosing even the option for `Play Services Resolver`:

[image]

- Restoring a backup of my project. Then deleting the `plugins` and `Google Mobile Ads` folders. Repeting the process and again didn't work.
- Deleting the three of them this time, importing them all from the downloaded package. Again can't resolve here, still don't appear the `PlayServicesResolver` menu.
- A few more (a bit messy), but none allowed me to achieve it.

What am I doing wrong? Any idea about what can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have compile errors in that project, It could be happened.

- After you import plugin, there some error messages but it can be removed if you cleared message but should fix that message.